# Integral bounds for a square with vertices $(\pm2,0), (0,\pm2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

In exercise X §1 1(e) from "Calculus of several variables" by Serge Lang (Third Edition), we are asked to

> Use Green's theorem to find the integral $\int_C y^2 \;dx+x\;dy$ When C is the following curve (taken counterclockwise) ... (e) The square with vertices $(\pm2,0), (0, \pm2)$.

[image]

I took this to mean
$$
\int_{-2}^0\int_{-2-x}^{2+x}(1-2y)dy\;dx+
\int_{0}^2\int_{x-2}^{2-x}(1-2y)dy\;dx
$$
which comes out to 0 according to my calculations. Checking in the back the answer was given as 8. I checked my work again and didn't find any error, but according to the explanation for the answer, see photograph below, the integral is just
$$
\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-2}^{2}(1-2y)dy\;dx
$$
[image]

I think the book's answer is wrong, but I am asking for your opinion because I would like to check that I haven't missed some obvious thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where the book got the double integral

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-2}^{2}\left(1-2y\right)dydx$$

because it equals $16$ when you evaluate it. Their integrand is correct (and yours too) because

$$
\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\y^2&x\end{bmatrix} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}y^2 = 1-2y.
$$

And then I decided to split the square in half (diamond). Using Green's Theorem for that left-half of the square, I got $\oint_C y^2dx + xdy$ to be

$$\int_{-2}^{0}\int_{-2-x}^{2+x}\left(1-2y\right)dydx = \int_{-2}^{0}\left(2x+4\right)dx = 4.$$

Using Green's Theorem for the other half of the square, I got $\oint_C y^2dx + xdy$ to be

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x-2}^{2-x}(1-2y)dydx = \int_{0}^{2}\left(-2x+4\right)dx = 4.$$

Adding them together gives us $8$, which according to you, is what the back of your book says.

I'm not sure what your calculation mistake was. Please let me know if I need to specify anything.

Comment: Yes I found a calculation mistake in my answer (sign mistake), so it does come out to 8 and the other answer is wrong since it is 16. I think it's an error in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The integration is over a rectangle $R$ of the form $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, then the double integral is the form $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)\, {\rm d}x\, {\rm d}y$.

> **Remark:** By Green's theorem we have$$\int_{C}P(x,y)\,{\rm d}x+Q(x,y)\,{\rm d}y=\iint_{\partial C}\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\, {\rm d}A$$
> where $C$ is a simple closed curve, piecewise smoothing and $\partial C$ the boundary of $C$.

All the hypothesis it holds, so by the Green's theorem we have
$$ \int_{C}y^{2}\, {\rm d}x+x\, {\rm d}y=\iint_{\partial C}\left(1-2y \right)\, {\rm d}A=\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(1-2y \right)\, {\rm d}x\, {\rm d}y$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. The question says the vertices of the square are at $(\pm2,0), (0,\pm2)$, which is a diamond shape centred at the origin. So it is not obvious to me why it is changed to being over a rectangle from $-2$ to $2$. I may have missed something, which is why I asked the question, but your answer doesn't help me see what I might have missed.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I have added more detail, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It is not clearer now, it is less clear if anything. If you change the variables, then you would also need to change the integrand, but you didn't even mention that in your original answer. After changing the variables in the way you suggest, the limits of integration are not $(-2,2)$ they would be $-\sqrt2,\sqrt2$. Regardless of whether your answer is correct or not, this is definitely not the intention of the answer in the book, since changes of variables have not been discussed at all by this section of the book.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but you're making it way too complicated. Just like Suzu Hirose said, if you change $x$ and $y$ to $x'$ and $y'$, then the integrand changes as well. And that double integral $\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-2}^{2}\left(1-2y\right)dydx$ equals 16.

Comment: If we change the density function, by 1. Then the double integral should represent the area. So, the book has a typo in both integrals. I have corrected this.

Comment: I just typed your double integral into a calculator. It equals $8$. @user1027216

Comment: @Accelerator Yes, that should happen because the same argument works as it did before. When we take the density to be 1, then the double integral represents the area of the region, which in this case is a rectangle of sides $2\sqrt{2}$ by $2\sqrt{2}$, with area $8 u^{2}$. The limits of integration make sense, because the Jacobian fits well. Anyway, I'll leave the clarification of the book type in this post.